# Maximo 5.2 Can upload attachment to the server but can't view them on client side

Tags: attachment, intranet, shared-directory, maximo

Ok I know Maximo 5.2 is horribly outdated but currently I just want to get the attachment working. So here is the situation:

I have an old server (running 2000) with a folder being shared on the network with the name of F$. I have tried that the attachment uploading functionality works fine: users can attach any file to a work order and that file will be copied into a specified folder in the F: drive of the server. But when I try to access to that file from the client side -- that is, click on the link within the work order (from attachment tab in Maximo webapp) in order to view the attachment -- I get a 404 response. So in a way it's like I am able to write to the server but somehow I can't read or download it from the client side.

UPDATE:
I found out that after you've uploaded a file to the server, it can be accessed from the link `http://servername:port/doclinks/drawings/filename` from any other client side desktop in the browser. However within the Maximo web app, the webpage javascript automatically parse the link as `http://servername/f$/MAXIMO/doclinks/drawings/filename` -- It returns redundant part and withno port number. Is this returned link configurable through settings or do I have to dig into the JSP?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Currently I am in no position to tinker with the server yet because there are some people still using it. I will try to create a sandbox and see if I could recreate the problem...but for now I guess I will just leave it as it is :(

Comment: The thing is I have no idea if this is a Maximo problem or an intranet shared folder sharing problem and I have limited knowledge to test actually (just a student here :P)

Comment: As a test you can make the saved image path a local drive where you have rights to it.

Comment: I tried to connect to the shared folder F: `http://servername:port/f$`, and the browser returned exactly the same 404 page as if I am trying to access an attachment within Maximo webapp. So I am guessing this is a folder sharing problem rather than Maximo? But how come I can still upload attachments through Maximo? Like I said, can write but cannot read =(

Comment: I don't think you can use f$ as a URL. You may need to make a persistent map to that drive using the `net use` command with the `/persistent` option to designate a local drive letter you can reference. This is why I suggested you try uploading and reading from a local drive path (somewhere on the C drive).

Comment: So here is what I've found out now: after you've uploaded a file to the server, it can be accessed from the link `http://servername:port/doclinks/drawings/filename`. However within the Maximo web app, javascript returns `http://servername/f$/MAXIMO/doclinks/drawings/filename`. It returns redundant part and withno port number. Is the returned link configurable through settings or I have to dig into the JSP?

Comment: It seems that the reason why javascript is returning that path is because that's the path set in **Manage all document folders** window where you define the folder that you will upload files to. The system seems to be simply taking that path `\\servername\f$\MAXIMO\doclinks\drawings\filename` and passes it on to browser directly which ends up with a 404 page..Is this a bug or configuration problem?

Comment: Look at mxe.doclink.path01 .. The first part is your physical file path (f drive) and then = your http link you updated above with the port.  `F<path>\maximo\doclinks=http://servername:port/doclinks`   You might also need to play with mxe.doclink.doctypes.defpath

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up virtual directory mapping on weblogic
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/weblogic_xml.html

The files are on the server. You just to correctly map the doclinks root on the file system to make it accessible to the web. You are getting a 404 error because the mapping is wrong.

In c:\maximo\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\WEB-INF look for weblogic.xml

Add an entry:

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>/apps/maximo/</local-path>
     <url-pattern>/doclinks/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

The entry above sits between `<weblogic-web-app>` and `</weblogic-web-app>`

The above example would mean your doclinks directory on the server is /apps/maximo/doclinks/

You would need to edit weblogic.xml, redeploy your maximo.ear along with your doclinks.

Comment: Hi, I followed the instruction manual and edited my doclinks.properties file.My default path is `mxe.doclink.doctypes.defpath = F:\\MAXIMO\\doclinks\\default` and my mapping route is `F<PATH>\\MAXIMO\\doclinks = http://servername:port/doclinks`. I checked the javascript from the client side, it calls openURL to the path which the file is uploaded, but still a 404. So editing doclinks.properties alone is not enough?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think Maximo 5.2 has the same structure as Maximo 6.28, there is no such directory under my root folder (`maximo\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\WEB-INF`)...should I be looking elsewhere for weblogic.xml file? I looked into my Maximo root folder (under F drive),and there are two weblogic.xml files under `activeportal\WEB-INF` and `mgmtconsole\WEB-INF` respectively, and they don't contain a lot of information at all. Sorry for asking for this much, I am actually trying to help to cleaning up a legacy system... :(

Comment: You can try creating the weblogic.xml in the directory structure I mentioned earlier. Just wrap the entry between `<weblogic-web-app>` and `<weblogic-web-app>`

Comment: This link seems to suggest virtual-directory-mapping is supported in WebLogic 7: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/793995?tstart=255

Comment: And this IBM doc suggests doclink functions the same for 5.2 up to 6.28: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296886

Comment: It's stretching my memory a bit, but I think `maximo\applications\maximo` in Maximo 6+ maps roughly to `MXServer` in Maximo 5.2. Obviously, that means that some of the directories from outside `maximo\applications\maximo` in the 6+ pathing were in a very differ path or non-existent in 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting `http://servername/f$/MAXIMO/doclinks/drawings/filename`, particularly the `f$/MAXIMO` part, it tells me your `F<PATH>\\MAXIMO\\doclinks = http://servername:port/doclinks` mapping in your `doclinks.properties` is not correct. If you are on the Maximo host, via remote desktop or whatever, and you open Windows Explorer, what do you need to put in the address bar to access the attached documents folder? You said it's on `F$`, but `F<PATH>` in your properties file will translate into `F:`, not `F$`. So, you need to change your doclinks.properties

from: `F<PATH>\\MAXIMO\\doclinks = http://servername:port/doclinks`

to: `\\\\servername\\F$\\MAXIMO\\doclinks = http://servername:port/doclinks`

Comment: You can set up your server to properly share a folder. Using F$ is not good practice. You can share the doclinks folder so the UNC path internally would just be `\\servername\doclinks`

Comment: @Sun Yes. If, as would be better practice, `servername` had `F:\MAXIMO\doclinks` shared as `doclinks` then the left side of the "to" assignment I gave should be `\\\\servername\\doclinks`, but then the other `doclinks.properties` that say where to put uploaded files should have corresponding changes made, and uploading would need to be retested, and even `docinfo` would need updating, since 5.2 only has the 1 mapping, not the `mxe.doclinks.path##` properties.